карусель Bootstrap с отображением нескольких элементов
работаю с Bootstrap,но уже очень долго бьюсь с одной проблемой. На странице сайта должно быть 3 карусели, одна обычная, которая отображает одну картинку которую можно перелистнуть и, вторая и третья, которая должна отображать максимальное число картинок в зависимости от ширины экрана.




.carousel {
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;

    .carousel-inner {
        .carousel-item {
            img {
                width: 500px;
                height: 360px;
                object-fit: cover;
            }
        }
    }

    .carousel-control-prev,
    .carousel-control-next {
        width: 51px;
        height: 51px;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        border-radius: 100%;
        left: -55px;
        background-color: $main-color;
        position: absolute;

    }




    .carousel-control-next {
        right: -55px;
        left: auto;

    }

    .carousel-control-prev-icon,
    .carousel-control-next-icon {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .carousel-overlay {
        display: flex;

        position: absolute; // Позволяет позиционировать над каруселью
        top: 10px; // Отступ сверху
        right: 10px; // Отступ справа
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); // Полупрозрачный фон
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 20; // Убедитесь, что overlay выше карусели и стрелок
    }

}
    <section class="piece-info">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main-page">
                <div class="left-info">

                    <div class="items-left">
                        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-indicators">
                                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0"
                                    class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"
                                    aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"
                                    aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="carousel-item active">
                                    <img src="img/img repair.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="img">
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <img src="img/img repair.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="img">
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <img src="img/img repair.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="img">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button"
                                data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                            </button>
                            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button"
                                data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>



видимо возникает какой-то конфликт между каруселями потому что я никак не могу создать эти три и чтобы они правильно работали.
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать возможным отображение нескольких картинок в карусели Bootstrap и сделать так чтобы все три карусели работали верно.

В сниппете у Вас одна карусель, приведите код остальных и поставьте релевантные метки относящиеся к вопросу, иначе велика вероятность что его не заметят.
